# Observe the MongoDB and perform actions accordingly if the tables are updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, database

So, I'm developing an application in Rails with mongodb as the database. So, this mongodb serves as a common database for 3 other websites.

Now, my problem is I also have another MySQL database(I know, my data is spread everywhere!!) and whenever this mongodb database is updated, I also want to update the MySQL database. Basically, I want to observe for any changes in the mongodb database and reflect the same changes to the MySQL.

Show me a way to accomplish this. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: This is actually quite broad though you may not be aware of it. The basic principle is that you need to follow the changes as committed to the [oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) of a replica set configuration. This is a record of "what is happening" with changes to your MongoDB. Everything will go there from inserts to updates, and it is required by MongoDB to implement replication between servers. You need to do some reading on that. Also there is other software that uses the same principle. The elasticsearch adapter for MongoDB as an example.

Comment: Help me rephrase the question so that it won't get closed. Will check out the oplog as well. Thank.

Comment: To understand here, what you are asking someone to "answer" is more like a series of articles than an answer in the scope of this site. Doing such a thing is a project in itself. I suggest following up on the suggestions I made earlier as that will provide you with the most information.

Comment: @VoodooChild92 Does MongoDB get updates through your application? Or it can change independently?

Comment: It changes independently as it's our central database which serves to 2-3 web services. If it doesn't, I would have happily used the rails observers.

Comment: I use mongoriver for this...It's totally independant from the rails app, which is good for many usage, just enable the oplog

Comment: @tomsoft Yes. Wrote the solution using Mongoriver.

Answer (score 1):

I found a precise solution for my need:

Using this gem called "MongoRiver": https://github.com/stripe/mongoriver

```
mongo = Mongo::MongoClient.from_uri(mongo_uri)
tailer = Mongoriver::Tailer.new([mongo], :existing)
outlet = YourOutlet.new(your_params)
stream = Mongoriver::Stream.new(tailer, outlet)
stream.run_forever(starting_timestamp)
```

In YourOutlet.rb, you define a class extending the Outlet class in the gem and define events like after_insert, after_update, before_insert, before_update etc. and they will be executed accordingly.

So, how this works is simple: As someone mentioned in the comments, you have to enable the Oplog in your MongoDB. And set a oplog size that's suitable to your need, usually of 1 GB.

Read about it here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/